# Unable to fetch organization details - unable to login

Tags: force.com, eclipse, login-errors, force.com-ide

UPDATE: 
The  weird thing is that i can able to login using same credentials to 
mavens-mate without any issue. Not sure why I'm unable to login using force.com IDE

After installing Eclipse and the Force.Com IDE. I then create a new Force.Com project and provide valid login information to my org I get the following error after a few seconds:

Unable to load org details, see the attached screen shot.

I can able to login to my dev box using the same credentials that I'm trying to login through eclipse force.com ide.
[image]

Comment: is it Sandbox or PROD ?

Comment: Is this a developer org? In that case you need to make a different selection for the environment.

Comment: its my free dev box and i have tried all options (sandbox/prod) none of them works for me.

Comment: there are 4 options avail 1) production/developer edition 2) sandbox 3) pre-release 4) other and I have tried all the options.

Comment: I would say upgrade your version of eclipse Force.Com Ide
Do you know which version are you using?

Comment: i have just installed and i have the latest update

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE Mars.1 release(4.5.1) and using this link to install force.com ide (http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42)

Comment: are you adding security token ?

Comment: yes i do and as shown in the screen shot

Comment: going through a proxy?

Comment: i do not have any proxy

Comment: If the latest version is 36.0, it has been known to cause issues. I am using version 35.0. At this point, I would suggest logging on from another computer.

Comment: how would you check the version of force.com ide? through eclipse?

Comment: Click on Help -> About Eclipse. In the dialog box that shows up, locate the icon for Force.com ide and click on it. You'll get a window "About Eclipse features" that will show you the version.

Comment: ok, i'm using 36.0.0

Comment: This is a issue with the force.com IDE 36.0 version. This is not related to your code. You can try to switch it to 35. and it will work perfectly. I also face this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that its known issue with force.com ide version 36 so I end-up roll-back to version 35

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your java to the latest version, in my case from 1.7 to 1.8.0_91, then restart your computer. 
Good luck